# Why does this classic ASP loop to split a textarea into lines not work?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to put a textarea into an array, splitting it where there are new lines. I know that docnos does in fact contain the characters found within the textarea. Can anyone please tell me why this doesn't work? It is not putting anything into the array for some reason.

```
docnos = dbencodeStr(Request.form("docnos"))
Dim myArray
myArray = Split(docnos, vbCrLf)

for i = 0 to UBound(myArray,2)
        tempstr = trim(myArray(0,i))
        strSQL = "insert into DocumentNumbers (queryid, documentnumber) values('"&queryid&"','"&tempstr&"');"
        Response.write(strSQL)
        Response.write(tempstr)
        Set rs = TransactionQueriesConn.Execute(strSQL, ,adCMdTExt)
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `myArray = Split(docnos, vbCrLf)`, `UBound(myArray,2)` will throw an "Subscript out of range" error (no second dimension). Remove the "On Error Resume Next".

Assuming `myArray` holds an one dimensional array of lines, the loop needs `UBound(myArray)` or `UBound(myArray,1)`.

If `docnos` contains `"234234234<BR>567567<BR>345345345"`, you need to Split on `<BR>`. Evidence:

```
>> s = "234234234<BR>567567<BR>345345345"
>> WScript.Echo Split(s, "<BR>")(1)
>>
567567
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. It's not splitting the text for some reason, however. It shows a value such as "234234234<BR>567567<BR>345345345"